# Which edition would be best: CE or EE?

Tags: magento2.3

**Requirement:**

- There will be five stores/websites. In the future, it will be more.
- Approx. 1M + products across the stores.
- Third-party integrations and product data sync.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you need to explore paid commerce edition EE

It's the number of products as this is in principal multiplied by the number of store views